# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu Error After jQuery Upgrade

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with jQuery 1.10. After upgrading to jQuery 3.5.1, I'm seeing this error in Chrome Developer Tools when clicking on a bootstrap dropdown menu item. Is there a way to get the menu working with the new version of jQuery and Bootstrap 3?

```
jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
at Function.se.error (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at se.tokenize (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at se.select (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at Function.se [as find] (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at S.fn.init.find (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at new S.fn.init (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at S (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at getParent (bootstrap.js:783)
at HTMLAnchorElement.Dropdown.toggle (bootstrap.js:708)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)

<div>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" id="myTabDrop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Reports <b 
   class="caret"></b></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1">
      <li><a href="AppealsReport.aspx">Appeals Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="Reports.aspx">Servicer Files</a></li>
      <li><a href="ProductivityReport.aspx">LA Productivity</a></li>                   
   </ul>
   </li>    
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Hi its working here is [code](https://jsfiddle.net/4swhg0j6/) with jquery 3.5.1 and bootstrap 3.4.1.

Comment: Works great, thanks. I'll need to update my bootstrap files too though.